# Javascript subtract time spans from each other

Tags: javascript, time, timespan

Suppose I have a time span `{"start_time":"8:30", "end_time":"18:00"}`

I want to subtract other time span like `{"start_time":"12:30", "end_time":"14:00"}` and get a result of:
 `[{"start_time":"8:30", "end_time":"12:30"},{"start_time":"14:00", "end_time":"18:00"}]`

EDIT: I will also require to subtract other time spans next e.g
`[{"start_time":"8:30", "end_time":"12:30"},{"start_time":"14:00", "end_time":"18:00"}]` - `{"start_time":"16:30", "end_time":"17:00"}` which should give me `[{"start_time":"8:30", "end_time":"12:30"},{"start_time":"14:00", "end_time":"16:30"},{"start_time":"17:00", "end_time":"18:00"}]`

I am wondering what is the best logical way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function subtract(t1, t2){
     return [{'start_time': t1.start_time, 'end_time': t2.start_time}, 
               {'start_time': t2.end_time, 'end_time': t1.end_time}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also want to subtract another time spans for example `{"start_time":"8:30", "end_time":"18:00"}` - `{"start_time":"12:30", "end_time":"14:00"}` - `{"start_time":"16:00", "end_time":"17:00"}`